# How can I debug a hang in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a python script that uses polars to scan through many thousands of parquet files in s3, do a join, and write the result to a local parquet file. Because of memory constraints, I have to run it in batches. It runs for an varying amount of time, and then just hangs. I can give a brief overview of the operations I'm carrying out below, but my main question is: what can I do to debug this?

I have tried using pl.Config.set_verbose(true), and it outputs a lot of logging on what's going on until it just decides to stop and hang. Ctrl-c does not quit it. Are there any other ways to even find out where it's hanging? Alternatively, is there a better way of carrying this out?

Summary of program:
I have a local parquet file, reference.parquet, that contains a list of valid IDs, let's call id_1. On s3, I have many directories each with two files of interest, file_a.parquet and file_b.parquet. file_a has two columns, id_1 and id_a, file_b has two columns, id_a and id_b. All of these IDs can appear multiple times. Ultimately, I want to end up with a global mapping table of every pair of id_1 and id_b that appears in all the files, with id_a being a join key between the two files, and id_1 appearing in reference.parquet.

1. I get the reference table as a cached lazy dataframe:

```py
ref = pl.scan_parquet("reference.parquet").select(pl.col("id_1")).cache()
```

2. Given an s3 base directory, create lazy dataframes for both file_a and file_b:

```py
def join_files(basedir):
  # basedir is something like "s3://bucket/dirname"
  df_a = (pl.scan_parquet(os.path.join(basedir, "file_a.parquet"))
          .join(ref, on="id_1"))
  df_b = (pl.scan_parquet(os.path.join(basedir, "file_b.parquet")))
  return (df_a.join(df_b, on="id_a")
          .select(["id_1", "id_b"])
          .unique())
```

3. For a batch of directories, use join_files to make a batch of lazy dataframes, concat them all, and return the unique values:

```py
def process_batch(dirs):
  dfs = [join_files(d) for d in dirs]
  # concatenate the dataframes, then execute.
  return pl.concat(dfs, rechunk=False).unique().collect()
```

Step 3 is where it inevitably hangs, when the concatenated lazy frames are being collected. Some variable number of batches will run, and then one will hang. When rerun, that batch will succeed, then a later one will hang.

Any theories or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your issue is that with all these LazyFrames, there are potentially that many open file handlers and sometimes the OS has, (to anthropomorphize), cut those ties. If that happens python/polars may be stuck waiting for the OS to give it the next line of a file and the OS is never going to provide it. To be clear, that's just conjecture, I have no way of knowing if that's what's happening.

You could try materializing (doing `.collect()`) sooner and, if necessary, save intermediate results to temp files to compensate for OOM.

Comment: I have cut down my batch size to 20, so 40 open files at a time. That shouldn't be an issue. I do now think the issue is with s3fs, as when I turn on s3fs debugging, it ultimately ends up issuing a HEAD request but never reading from it. Might there be an issue with issuing many s3fs reads from a parallel collect?

The whole batching strategy is to implement your second strategy, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if I collect and lazy the reference table instead of just using cache(), there are no hangs.

The reference table is a very large file, and there is actually some filtering done on it before the cache call. Every single subquery joins against the ref table to filter out only desired items. I would have thought that .cache() would be more or less equivalent to .collect().lazy().